# Change naming schema of first level associations in to_xml (ActiveRecord::Serialization)

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

ActiveRecord's [to_xml](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_xml) serialization lets you include first level assocations (with :include), as well as change the naming convention (by :dasherize or :camelize). Putting the two together looks like this:

```
  firm.to_xml :dasherize => false, include: :account
```

This only changes the naming convention on firm's fields, and not account's. I've tried the following, which throws back syntax errors:

```
  firm.to_xml :dasherize => false, include: :account {:dasherize => false}
  firm.to_xml :dasherize => false, include: {:account {:dasherize => false}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Ruby 1.9.x or above:

```
firm.to_xml dasherize: false, include: { account: { dasherize: false } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
  firm.to_xml :dasherize => false, include: {:account => {:dasherize => false}}
```